# How do I get a $_REQUEST variable?

Tags: symfony

I would like to pass a variable to my controller and I need to get its value regardless of its request method (POST or GET), the equivalent of $_REQUEST['myvar'], how do I do this?

Comment: `$_SERVER` is a superglobal, it's available from everywhere. You can just use it wherever you need it. Similar to `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get url attribute which is a part of a route you have to do something like this (in controller):

```
$request->attributes->get(<attribute_name>);
```

If you need to get POST or GET parameter you have to use this code:

```
$request->get(<parameter_name>);
```

If you need to get value of $_SERVER array you have to do this:

```
$request->server->get(<server_key_name>); //$request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer... Instead of using one of the following:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $request->query->get('myvar'); //gets GET var.
    $request->request->get('myvar'); //gets POST var.
    ...
```

I need to call **get** on the **Request** class

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{

    $myvar = $request->get('myvar', null);
    ...
```

Comment: You don't need to pass `null` to the `get` method as it is already the default value.